# MySQL 5.6.14 cannot detect data created from MySQL 5.6.11

Tags: mysql, database, backup, detect, workbench

I have a created a database called "global" in MySQL 5.6.11.
The data files are stored in a separate folder from MySQL installation directory. Hence the database "global" can be clearly located in folder "global" in Windows Explorer.
What I did was, copy that entire folder to another directory for backup purposes.

Due to a bug in mysqldump.exe (5.5.16) which state that it has older version that the MySQL server (5.6.11), so I decided uninstall everything and remove every data (not the backup).

Then I install MySQL 5.6.14. And I copied back the "global" folder from backup to the root data directory of the new MySQL installation. When I open MySQL Workbench, it can detect the database. I even expand the "tables" node and able to see the list of tables in it.

Surprisingly, when I tried to query the data, MySQL showed an error those tables do not exist. Every single table does not exist everytime I query it by using simple syntax:    select * from account. I even used the command line, but it still doesn't work.

Does someone know why?